# How to use QGIS plugins functionality in standalone application

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, c++, standalone

I'm new to QGIS 3 Library to develop standalone map application in qt4, C++ language. I was wondering if there is any way that I can use QGIS plugins such as Advanced viewshed analysis, Contour plugin and so on by:

1. creating a dll library by rewriting the python code to c++ after obtaining the plugins source code from github(with credits of course, will have to study Python since am more of c++ developer)
2. writing a wrapper around the code

If anyone have done one of the above please tell me which one is better and where to start.

Sorry for my poor English, as it's my second language.

Comment: First of all QGIS 3 is Qt5. Second, it should be technically possible with the API to recreate the mechanism for integrating plugins in your custom app. But it would be very complicated
You might want to consider other approaches:
* use QGIS and simply customize the UI it to your need and use a plugin
* create a custom app in Python which would make it easier to reuse existing plugins.

Comment: Sorry for confusing Qgis 3 with Qt5 and thank you for your reply. Both options are good but in my situation since I'll be new to Python programming and also need to integrate my custom map to other modules written in C++.

Comment: Again sorry for the confusion  Denis Rouzaud, I'm using the Qgis 3 library using Qt creator 3 and qt 4 library. but you can not use Qgis 3 in Pyqt 4 environment. that's the difference

Comment: neither you can use QGIS 3 with Qt 4....